# Why am I getting "No issuer certificate for certificate in certification path found" error for a known and trusted certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am trying to connect to a server with a Java Http client to make a web service call. If I turn net debugging on with the below code..

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
```

I am seeing that certificates from Entrust seem to be added as trusted certificates. Among those added were the below...

```
 adding as trusted cert:
 Subject: CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048), OU=(c)    1999   Entrust.net Limited, OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), O=Entrust.net
 Issuer:  CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048), OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited, OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), O=Entrust.net
 Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x3863def8
 Valid from Fri Dec 24 12:50:51 EST 1999 until Tue Jul 24 10:15:12 EDT 2029
```

It seems as if the server is using a cert from Entrust because I also see in the debug...

```
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 2649
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] =   [0]         Version: 3
     SerialNumber: 1356119177
       IssuerDN: C=US,O=Entrust\, Inc.,OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms,OU=(c) 2012 Entrust\, Inc. - for authorized use only,CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K
       Start Date: Wed Jul 15 11:50:20 EDT 2015
       Final Date: Sun Jul 15 18:27:04 EDT 2018
```

And yet during the handshake process I get the below exception...

```
***
Caught: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: 
No issuer certificate for certificate in certification path found.
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
```

Comment: The `IssuerDN` is not the same as the trusted cert you showed, so it is likely an intermediate cert, and you don't have the intermediate cert in your trust store. A good server would have included intermediate certs, so if you have control of the server, fix that. Otherwise find and add the intermediate cert to your trust store.

Comment: According to this it should be enough if I have the root cert in my trust store without having to add the intermediate cert http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83874/in-order-to-trust-the-digital-certificate-does-immediate-ca-cert-also-needs-to

Comment: Did you read the [second answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/83885) in that link? Let me re-cap for you, repeating what I already said: Servers are *supposed* to include intermediate certs in their handshake, in which case only the root cert needs to be in your trust store. *Bad* servers don't, so your trust store will need to have those intermediate certs too, for things to work. If you have any say with the server, make it a *good*, well-behaved server. Otherwise, add intermediate cert to your trust store, so you can interact with the misbehaving server.

Comment: So you are saying the server might not be including an intermediate cert and so in that case I need to request the people who own that server to send me an intermediate cert to add to my trust store? I guess I am not clear on is that cert missing on the server side or on my side (client's trust store)?

Comment: In order for actual server cert to be verified, the entire cert *chain* must be available, and the root cert must be trusted. If the intermediate cert is missing, the server cert cannot be verified. As I said, a *good* server will include the intermediate cert(s) in the SSL handshake. A badly configured server will not, but you can work around that problem by installing the intermediate cert in your own trust store. It's a workaround for badly configured servers, so it'd be better to get the server configured correctly, but the workaround works, so use it if server cannot be fixed.

Comment: The two certificates you listed are not the same. Different serial numbers. (Clever of Java to give you one serial number in hex and one in decimal.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding server certificate to my java client (jre's cacerts and jssecacerts).

If we add a certificate to java client this way we are asking our jre to trust this server's certificate.

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.xyz.com:443 2>&1 |
sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/cert.pem

#cacerts
keytool -import -alias certname -file /tmp/cert.pem -keystore
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

#jssecacerts(Normally we remove this file)
keytool -import -alias certname -file /tmp/cert.pem -keystore
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts -storepass changeit
```

If this piece of client code is executed via application server , please **restart your application server**.

Make sure you have **openssl, keytool** in enviornment variables and change your respective JAVA_HOME location.

Answer (score -3):

I got around this problem by creating a Trust Manager which accepts the server's certificate and pointed my Apache HttpClient to use that Trust Manager...

```
 private class TrustAll implements X509TrustManager
{
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException
{
}

public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException
{
}

public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
{
    return new X509Certificate[0];
}
```

}

```
TrustManager[] trustArray = [new TrustAll()] as TrustManager[]
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
ctx.init(null, trustArray, null);

// create an http client builder
HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
 httpClientBuilder.setSslcontext(ctx)

 httpclient = httpClientBuilder.build();
```

Comment: That trust manager accepts any certificate whatsoever. It is radically insecure. Do not use.